# Magento move currency symbol out of span for microformats

Tags: magento, microformats

I am working on Magento 1.7.0.2 and in

```
app\design\frontend\default\default\template\catalog\product\price.phtml
```

on line 201 (ish) is

```
 <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price, true, true) ?>
```

Which produces the code:

```
<span class="price">£100.00</span>
```

Because the currency symbol is in the span, it gets an error in microformats.  So I want the price to look the same but take the currency symbol out of the span so  it will look like:

```
£<span class="price">100.00</span>
```

How would I do that?  What is $_coreHelper->currency($_price, true, true) doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is $_coreHelper->currency($_price, true, true) doing ?

```
/**
 * Convert and format price value for current application store
 *
 * @param   float $value
 * @param   bool $format
 * @param   bool $includeContainer
 * @return  mixed
 */
public static function currency($value, $format = true, $includeContainer = true)
```

i.e add currency symbol and enclose it into `<span class="price"><span>` so if you would use $_coreHelper->currency($_price, true, false) you would get the same price without `<span class="price">`

If you need to use `£<span class="price">100.00</span>`

```
 <?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(); ?>
<span class="price"><?php echo $price ?></span>
```

`<?php echo $_price ?>` - is not a final version of your code, you need to format it but without currency symbol, you can read it [on Magento SE topic  - how to get price without currency symbol](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10088/how-to-get-price-without-currency-symbol)

Smth like

```
Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->format(
    $product->getFinalPrice(), 
    array('display'=>Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL), 
    false
);
```

Comment: I did this which seems simpler, after reading your explanation? Your currency php code then -
     <span class="price">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price, false, false) ?></span>

Comment: you could also have the monetary value inserted via css dynamic content using .price::before{}.

Comment: @albert - thats a good one.  It will save re formatting all the £ that are now out of the css styling class of price.  Ill take a look

Comment: i gotcha man. i'll respond as an answer, even if you don't want to accept it

Comment: <?php echo number_format($_product->getPrice(), 2);   ?>  with alberts css currency insert below

Answer (score 1):

you can add the currency character as dynamic content using :before,:after and inserting it character via content=""; like so:

```
.price{position:relative; text-align:center; outline:1px solid #000; width:200px; height:60px}
.price:before,.price::before{content:'£'; position:absolute; z-index:12; font-size:50px; left:0; top:0; width:200px; height:60px; text-align:left}
.price:after,.price::after{}
```

i whipped up a quick fiddle showing it in action http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/7MDH5/2/

Comment: Fairly extreme example!  I just used - .price:before,.price::before{content:'\00A3';}    http://jsfiddle.net/7MDH5/3/   Not sure the difference between :before and ::before, and I probably have to make the class more specific to my page so it wont appear on my site where I dont want it, but thanks!

Comment: Yeah the css solution is the best work around for me as the pound sign gets the same css as the price it is matching, so less side affects.  Thanks.  [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before]  The ::before notation was introduced in CSS 3 in order to establish a discrimination between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. Browsers also accept the notation :before introduced in CSS 2.

Comment: Using css loses the currency tag so something like <abbr class="currency" title="GBP"> is needed.  And close it or something.